# Riemann integrability of piece wise function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Determine if the function $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, where
$f(x) \text{ defined by}
$\begin{cases}
                                   0 & \text{if $x=\pm\frac{1}{n}, n\in\mathbb{N}$ or $x=0$} \\
                                   1 & \text{if $x>0$ and $x\neq\frac{1}{n}. n\in\mathbb{N}$} \\
  -1 & \text{if $0>x$ and $x\neq-\frac{1}{n}, n\in\mathbb{N}$}
\end{cases}
is  Riemann integrable or not. If it is Riemann integrable, then evaluate $$\int_{-1}^{1}f.$$
So far what I have done is:

For every $\varepsilon>0$ consider $$\left[-\frac{\varepsilon}{8},\frac{\varepsilon}{8}\right]$$

$$(M-m)\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{8}-\frac{-\varepsilon}{8}\right)=2(\varepsilon/4)=\varepsilon/2.$$

I suspect $$\int_{-1}^{1}f=0$$ (in case $f$ is integrable. Now, I need to properly show that $f$ is integrable, my intuition tells me it is.
But I got stuck here. How can I proceed? Would Darboux sums be useful in this exercise?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what your current attempt has to do with the exercise. What do you think the answer is? Do you know the definition of Riemann integrability? It is possible to explicitly write down partitions for this function and interval (which I'm implicitly saying is therefore integrable) and evaluate the integral in this way.

Comment: @davidlowryduda I tried to explicitely define the partitions but I could not do it. And yes, I know the definition of Riemann integrability but I'm more comfortable using the Darboux definition. I think $\int_{-1}^{1}f=0$ (if it exists), but I'm not sure how to justify the integrability of such function.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that a bounded function with finite number of discontinuities is Riemann integrable? Next split the interval $[-1,1]$ into three intervals $[-1,-\epsilon],[-\epsilon, \epsilon], [\epsilon, 1]$ and note that the function has a finite number of discontinuities in first and third intervals. Deal with the middle interval and show that Darboux sums differ by small amount.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, I'm aware of that fact. But with this particular problem I'm having a hard time seeing why there are finitely many discontinuities. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are finite discontinuities on each of the intervals $[-1,-\epsilon] $ and $[\epsilon, 1]$ so that is taken care of. We only need to handle the middle interval $[-\epsilon, \epsilon] $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that is precisely what I am strugglin with: seeing why the discontinuities are finite on $[-1,\epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon, 1]$. Once again, thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: The discontinuities of $f$ are $\pm \frac1n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0$.  On $[\epsilon, 1]$, we can ignore the negative numbers as well as $0$, so it just amounts to solving $\epsilon \leq \frac1n \leq 1$ for $n$, giving $1 \leq n \leq \frac1\epsilon$.  That's a bounded interval, so it only has finitely many natural numbers in it.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks! I understand your comment, but the following question arised:  Doesn't the interval $ [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ contain infinitely many discontinuities since there are infinitely many points of the form $\pm1/k$? where $k$ is natural.

Comment: For example, if $-1/n_0$ is the greatest number such that $-1/n_0\leq -\epsilon$, then we have that $-1/1=-1<-1/2<-1/3<...<-1/n_0\leq -\epsilon$. Bu there are infinitely many naturals $m$ greater than $n_0$, and therefore there are infinitely many numers $-1/m$ (where $m>n_0)$. So these $-1/m$'s belong to $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$.

Comment: You are correct that there are infinitely many discontinuities on $[-\epsilon, \epsilon]$, but this doesn't matter, as the length of this interval may be made as small as we wish and $M-m \leq 2$ is bounded, making its contribution to the integral negligible.